# Can we run appium test scripts through flask server on locally connected device

Tags: html, forms, flask, webserver, python-appium

I am trying to run my appium scripts on button click in a html template, but unfortunately I have searched everywhere but still I found no solution.
My html template is inside a templates folder in the flask project directory and I am taking path as an input and want to pass that string to my Appium script and as soon as I click on the Submit button on my template it should launch the test script on my locally connected phone taking the path as a parameter.
Any kind of help will be appreciated.
Regards

I tried adding functions of my test script in the flask route but I have multiple functions in my python script and for every function I would have to create multiple routes. I was expecting to run the python script all at once on the default flask route ('/').

Following is my code for flask_server.py file as per now I am just getting the parameter in it and showing it in the next route but instead I want to pass my appium script here and run it on device on submit.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request

from Instagram.instagram_android_automation import 
InstagramAndroidAutomation

from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/dashboard/<name>')
def dashboard(name):
   return 'welcome %s' % name

@app.route('/login',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    user = request.form['name']
    return redirect(url_for('dashboard',name = user))
  else:
    user = request.args.get('name')
    return render_template('login.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Added it, any help would be great